# AWS Amplify sorting a connection doesn't work

Tags: aws-amplify

I just want to do a very simple sort by a single field. Not interested in any composite keys or anything. Just want a primary key, and then to be able to sort on the `order` field. The docs are pretty unclear on how to get this to happen, so I won't be surprised if I've done something wrong. An example of this very simple use-case would be nice.

My schema is:

```
type SurveyTemplate @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  sections: [SectionTemplate] @connection
}

type SectionTemplate @model @key(fields: ["id", "order"]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  order: Int!
  allowMultiple: Boolean!
  isSubsection: Boolean!
  sections: [SectionTemplate] @connection
}
```

My query is:

```
query surveyQuery($surveyTemplateId: ID!) {
  getSurveyTemplate(id: $surveyTemplateId) {
    id
    sections(limit: 20, sortDirection: ASC, filter: { isSubsection: { eq: false } }) {
      items {
        id
        order
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding is I've created a primary key on `id`, and a secondary index on `order` that can be used to sort it, but the results do not come back sorted by the `order` field either ascending or descending. What am I missing?